# GridView with a vertical height of exactly 50%

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a `GridView` that contains tile-like buttons, wherein this number can vary within certain boundaries. I want this `GridView` to appear on the bottom of the screen with a given height (say, for example, 50%).
Using a vertical `LinearLayout` and weights I am able to make the `GridView` be exactly 50% high, but the buttos within it are bigger such that the v turns into a scrollable area.

How can I avoid this? I want the buttons within to scale exactly such that the `GridView` contains all of them without scrolling and such that it takes up 50% of the screen. Is a `GridView` maybe even the wrong choice?

I'll not post code for now because this is not a specific problem, but more of a general question of how to approach this. If needed, I'll of course post what I got so far.

*Edit*: I tried to use a `TableLayout` now, but the cells won't stretch to the screen width. Other threads say this is fixed using the (correct) `LayoutParams`, but it doesn't work for me. My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_weight="1" ></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/example_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" ></TableLayout>        
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

and the `Fragment` I am using it in

```
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_example, container, false );
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );

    TableLayout.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
    TableRow.LayoutParams cellParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById( R.id.example_table );
    for( int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 10; rowIndex++ ) {
        TableRow currentRow = new TableRow( getActivity() );

        for( int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 2; columnIndex++ ) {
            TextView cell = new TextView( getActivity() );
            cell.setBackgroundColor( Color.GREEN );
            cell.setText( "Foo" );

            currentRow.addView( cell, cellParams );
        }

        table.addView( currentRow, rowParams );
    }
}
```

It displays the table, but the cells are as narrow as possible, i.e. they barely wrap around the word. I want the cells to stretch over the entire screen width, though. The table also is in the middle of the page, not on the bottom where I would expect it to be(?)

*Edit #2*: Okay, never mind, I figured it out. I have to set the `weight` basically everywhere, then it works.

Comment: *Is a GridView maybe even the wrong choice?* - as you want to show all of its items then you could simply use a `TableLayout`(or other layouts) and avoid the hassle with the adapter. Otherwise you can keep the `GridView` but you'll need a custom adapter where you'll set the height of the items so that all will fit on the target area.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The number of columns depends on the device width, but I can just as well do that with a `TableLayout`. I'll check  & try it out and see how it works out.

Comment: I tried it, but there are still problems. See the update in my question.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Now let's see how well it'll work out.

Comment: I didn't expect that you'd be using a `TableLayout` with the content in another weighted `TableLayout`(which will not go well). Check this out if you still have problems(https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6099647).

Comment: For now it – finally – works and I'll just see where it goes from here. I also simplified the XML as the inner `TableLayout` doesn't need to be in its own `TableRow`.